# error while using Python.h

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-3.x, cython

I just wrote a simple c code to check if Python.h is working or not

```
#include<Python.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("this is a python header file included programm\n");
    return 0;
}
```

As obvious it does not do much.The problem is when i try to compile it with gcc it gives error.

```
foo.c:1:19: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory.
```

Then i tried to check if my python-dev package has Python.h installed or not using locate.

```
$locate Python.h
```

which gave me the path as

```
$/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

Now, it is clear that i have Python.h header file on my system.How do i get it working?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-I/usr/include/python2.7` to your `CFLAGS`?

Answer (score 0):

try instaling:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

when compile run something like this:

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/python2.7 -lpython2.7  nameOfProgram.c -o name
```